# Amazon S3 HTML Title

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to change the `<title></title>` attribute on an S3 page (in the `<head>`)? For example, I have an application/pdf file publicly available, but when you go to the link it shows a very long title. I was wondering if there's some kind of meta data attribute where one can set the page's title.

Comment: A PDF file doesn’t have any `head` or `title` elements – simply because it is _not_ an HTML document. If you have a reference to the window the PDF file is opened in, and it is a different window, you could try and set `document.title` via JavaScript: other than that, you’d need to create an HTML document that you link to, and that then in turn embeds the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF files do contain title metadata, but it's embedded directly in the PDF file itself, and doesn't have to do with the server architecture. Due to the binary nature of PDF files it's not a tag like `<title></title>` is in HTML, and it's not editable using a text editor. It can only be edited with a PDF editing tool.

Most dedicated PDF editing software will allow you to edit PDF metadata and specify your own title. As an example, here is how to do it in Adobe Acrobat Pro:

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF18.html